# Trig substitution or part integration

Tags: integration

How can I integrate the following function:
$$\int \frac{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}{x^6}\,dx $$
? I've tried integration by parts but I think I'm doing in the wrong way.
I need some help!

Comment: Use x=sin(u) and dx=cos(u)du

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int \frac{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}{x^6}\,dx $$

Substitute $x=\sin(u)$ and $dx=\cos(u) du$. Then $(1-x^2)^{3/2}=(1-\sin^2(u))^{3/2}=\cos^3(u)$ and $u=\sin^{-1}(x)$

$$\int \frac{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}{x^6}\,dx =$$
$$\int \cot^4(u)\csc^2(u) du$$

For the intergrand $\cot^4(u)\csc^2(u)$ substitute $s=\cot(u)$ and $ds=-\csc^2(u) du$

$$\int \cot^4(u)\csc^2(u) du=\int s^4 ds$$

The integral of $s^4$ is $\frac{s^5}{5}$

$$\int s^4 ds=-\frac{s^5}{5}+C$$

Substitute back for $s=\cot(u)$ and $u=\sin^{-1}(x)$

$$-\frac{s^5}{5}+C=-\frac{1}{5}\cot\left(\sin^{-1}x\right)^5+C$$

Simplify using $\cot(\sin^{-1}(z))=\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{z}$

$$-\frac{1}{5}\cot\left(\sin^{-1}x\right)^5+C=\frac{\left(1-x^2\right)^{5/2}}
{5x^5}+C$$

So:

$$\int \frac{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}{x^6}\,dx=\frac{\left(1-x^2\right)^{5/2}}
{5x^5}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

By substituting $x=\sin\theta$ we are left with:

> $$\int\frac{\cos^4\theta}{\sin^6\theta}\,d\theta = \color{red}{C-\frac{\cot^5\theta}{5}}.$$